# Direct download location for MySQL Workbench?

Tags: wget

I'm working on a bash script that installs various applications, and one of those is the latest version of MySQL Workbench. Since Workbench's presence (and version) in Linux repositories is hit-or-miss, I have decided to just download it from dev.mysql.com.

However, it seems their website isn't friendly to `wget` or similar downloaders that require a direct link.

Is there a direct link to the latest versions of MySQL Workbench (preferably using dev.mysql.com, one of its mirrors, or an otherwise vetted source)?

Comment: Which flavor of Linux are you using?

Comment: Currently, I'm testing on Ubuntu 11.10 x64, but I'll need the direct links to the versions for Mac, Windows, and both RPM and Deb based Linux (32 and 64 bit). Unless it's something convoluted, I should be able to figure out the rest if I get even one, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench 6.2.4 for Windows 64-bit: http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.2.4-winx64.msi

Comment: I no longer need this, since I don't use the script anymore, but egads! They really don't make it easy, do they?

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest version:

1. Search this page for "mysql-workbench-community-" and copy the filename you need: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
2. Paste it after this link: http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/

For example: http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.2.5-winx64.msi